# How can I get the selected radio button in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to get the selected button from a group of radio buttons.

For instance, how does it work in code like this?

```
<input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
<label for="html">HTML</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
<label for="css">CSS</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
<label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
```

Comment: Use `checked={true}` property in the input element you want.  Ex: `<input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML" checked={true}/>`

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Let's say that there is a function that gets the selected button from these radio button. How would it look like?

Comment: With react, actually your state should already *know/reflect* which of those radios is selected. You would not *derive* it from the html, it's the other way around, you would *apply* it to the html.

Comment: @Yoshi Do you have any documentation to read? I'm using class components.

Comment: @asemshaat I think antima99's answer shows it quite clearly.

Answer (score 2):

In React, the function onChangeValue() is attached with div so as soon as the user selects any radio button, it will be reflected in the function.

When the user is done with the selection, they may want to submit the form. The submit method is called formSubmit().

```
 /*
 * A simple React component
 */
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params)
        // Initial gender state set from props
        this.state = {
            gender: this.props.gender
        }
        this.setGender = this.setGender.bind(this)
    }

    setGender(e) {
        this.setState({
            gender: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {gender} = this.state
        return  <div>
            Gender:
                <div>
                  <input type="radio" checked={gender == "male"}
                         onClick={this.setGender} value="male" /> Male
                  <input type="radio" checked={gender == "female"}
                         onClick={this.setGender} value="female"  /> Female
                </div>
            { "Select Gender: " } {gender}
            </div>;
    }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<App gender="male" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Let's say that there is a function that gets the selected button from these radio button. How would it look like?

Comment: i have updated my answer with an update!

Comment: I see. That sounds a good answer

Comment: But what does `this.setGender = this.setGender.bind(this)` do?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Keep a handler function like this

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    alert(`${name} : ${value}`);
  };
```

And attach as a `onChange` handler.

```
<input
   type="radio"
   id="html"
   name="fav_language"
   value="HTML"
   onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-moon-xi1co?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @asem shaatm,  check this out !!

Answer (score 1):

Add an `onChange` handler to the parent element and, in that function, grab the id from the element that was clicked. Depending on your requirements you might then want to store that id in state.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { selected: '' };
  }

  // Destructure the id from the clicked element
  // and set the state with it
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target;
    this.setState({ selected: id }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.selected);
    });
  }

  // Add handleChange as the handler for
  // the onChange listener
  render() {
    return (
      <div onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML" />
        <label for="html">HTML</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS" />
        <label for="css">CSS</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript" />
        <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

And a functional component version.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState('');

  // Destructure the id from the clicked element
  // and set the state with it
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { id } = e.target;
    setSelected(id);
  }

  // Log the state after its been updated
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selected) console.log(selected);
  }, [selected]);

  // Add handleChange as the handler for
  // the onChange listener
  return (
    <div onChange={handleChange}>
      <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML" />
      <label for="html">HTML</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS" />
      <label for="css">CSS</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript" />
      <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Historically, tag `input` didn't need an end. Maybe it does now. Can you add a reference?

Comment: Re *"the input and br elements were missing their closing tags."*: [It validates just fine](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/input_tag.html) without "/>" at the end of tag `input` (check options *"source"* and *"outline"* to see the HTML source in the output). The same for `br`. That isn't to say it shouldn't be done (e.g., for consistency). It definitely should.

Comment: I guess I'm still in XHTML-mode. Thanks for the comment. [I did a little reading.](https://hackr.io/blog/difference-between-html-html5-xhtml). @PeterMortensen